# AfterRedirect call back not woking

Tags: javascript, php, html, callback, payment-gateway

I created session in php and navigate to the sample Mastercard payment gateway.I cansucessfully navigate to it but I cannot obtain the data  from afterRedirect function passed by beforeRedirect function. It seems to be afterRedirect funtion doesn't work. Is it because security conditions in payment gateway. Can you offer some help to solve this problem. I want to bring back passed data like orderId, sessionId ....

Here are my functions,

```
    function beforeRedirect() {
        return {
            successIndicator: successIndicator,
            orderId: orderId,
            sessionId: sessionId,
            sessionVersion: sessionVersion,
            merchantId: merchantId
        };
    }

    function afterRedirect(data) {
        //return;
        //return false;
    // Compare with the resultIndicator saved in the completeCallback() method
        if (resultIndicator) {
            var result = (resultIndicator === data.successIndicator) ? "SUCCESS" : "ERROR";
            window.location.href = "payment-complete.php/" + data.orderId + "/" + result;
            //break;
        }
        else {
            successIndicator = data.successIndicator;
            alert(successIndicator);
            orderId = data.orderId;
            sessionId = data.sessionId;
            sessionVersion = data.sessionVersion;
            merchantId = data.merchantId;

            window.location.href = "payment-complete.php/" + data.orderId + "/" + data.successIndicator + "/" + data.sessionId;
        }
    }
   
   
    function completeCallback(response) {
        console.log("completeCallback", sessionId);
        console.log("completeCallback", response);
        console.log("completeCallback", Checkout);
        console.log(successIndicator);
        alert();
            
            //console.log("hello");
            
            
            console.log("completeCallback", response);

            var sParam = "completeCallback " + orderId + " " + response;

            // Save the resultIndicator
            resultIndicator = response;
            var result = (resultIndicator === successIndicator) ? "SUCCESS" : "ERROR";

            //window.location.href = "/hostedCheckout/" + orderId + "/" + result;
            window.location.href = "payment-complete.php"+ orderId + "/" + result;;
    }


    Checkout.configure({
        session: {
            id: sessionId
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand how your flow exactly goes. You seem to be navigation to a payment-complete.php file with some params. But I don't see where the payment-gateway comes into contact. It would be helpful if you could perhaps share some documentation you've followed for this?